# H.264 encoder Filter for Directshow that controls bitrate and GOP Settings in Win32 CPP Project

Tags: winapi, h.264, directshow, ms-media-foundation, graphedit

I'm Working to control Bitrate and GOP Settings using H.264 DirectShow Filter. For that when I have gone through H.264 AMCAP application I have found this H.264 control dialog box. Now from where can I get this dialog box. Do I need any support from Media Foundation to get this dialog box. Is these control box is the filter properties from standard Directshow filters or any customised filters.

[image]

Comment: You already asked a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244900/h-264-bitrate-and-gop-control-settings-using-directshow that was closed. Please explain how is this different or why Roman's answer is not relevant again